# Does USB wifi adapter have to work on host in order to use it on virtual machine?

Tags: usb, wifi, adapter

Just a general question:  is their a rule that says a usb wifi adapter must be compatible with a host OS in order to use that usb wifi adapter on a guest virtual machine?

Comment: Generally no, though there can be some annoying pathologies in how some oddball multi-mode devices respond to being enumerated once by the host and then again when claimed by the guest, or worse if the guest's driver has to tell the device to re-enumerate in a different mode, as is quite common with GSM dongles.  You may want to pre-arm the VM settings to claim particular VID/PID combination(s) before plugging in the device to use, rather than trying to manually switch it after the host OS stack has gnawed on it for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

No, the USB device just has to work well enough for the virtualization software's USB drivers in the host operating system to attach to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info.